# Inserting a random time

Tags: javascript, jquery

when clicking to insert time im getting a random number, i need to get a random time after 20 minutes from the current time field and not later than 40 minutes.

random acceptable times are between 22:50 and 23:30

```js
function myFunction() {
  const s = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 * 60) + 20 * 60;
  const value = Math.floor(s / 60) + ':' + ('0' + (s % 60)).slice(-2);
  timeout.value = value;
}
```

```html
   
<input type="text" id="time" value="22:30" name="time"><br>
<input type="text" id="timeout" name="timeout"><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">inser time</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a random number of minutes between 20 and 40 and add that to the current date.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const now = new Date;
  const [h, m] = document.getElementById("time").value.split(":");
  now.setHours(h);
  now.setMinutes(m);
  const minutes = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21) + 20;
  now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() + minutes);
  timeout.value = now.getHours() + ":" + String(now.getMinutes()).padStart(2, '0');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="time" value="22:30" name="time"><br>
<input type="text" id="timeout" name="timeout"><br>
<button onclick="myFunction()">inser time</button>
```